# Strapi throws 'timeout of 6000ms exceeded' error when registering new users for the first time

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, vite, strapi, railway

I have a system composed of a PostgreSQL database, a Strapi application, and a React + Vite application, all deployed on Railway. When a new client tries to register in my application for the first time, the initial registration request fails with the "timeout of 6000ms exceeded" error. However, subsequent requests work fine. This issue is critical, as sometimes the user is registered but doesn't receive the confirmation email, leaving them stuck in the process. Any insights into why this is happening and how I can resolve it to ensure smooth and reliable registration of new users in my Strapi application?

I updated my Strapi to the latest version along with all available packages. After redeploying the application and conducting tests, everything initially seemed to work correctly. I even had some individuals register to confirm that the system was functioning properly, and there were no issues during this initial testing phase. However, a recurring issue arises where every new user, on their first registration attempt, encounters the 'timeout of 6000ms exceeded' error. It's important to note that this problem is consistent for all users; it affects each user's initial registration attempt. Subsequent registration attempts by the same or different users work without errors.

To provide more context:

After the initial deployment, I asked several people to register to validate the system's functionality, and everything worked as expected during this initial testing.
However, as the day progresses, the problem reappears, and new users continue to face the 'timeout' error on their first registration attempt.
Additionally, some users do not receive the confirmation email despite being registered, which hinders the onboarding process and their access to the application.
I expected the registration process to function smoothly for every user, but the issue seems to be tied specifically to the initial registration attempt for each user. This problem persists even after some time has passed since the deployment. Any insights or solutions to address this consistent issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whose error is it?  The database server, the app server, something else?  Look in the log files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Definitely check the logs.  This error can be caused on the server where your project is deployed.

I recently deployed my Strapi app using Render as hosting, and I did not run into issues.

So I would guess with our seeing the logs.  That this would be a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the problem was in the connection of strapi and postgres, locally everything was working fine, but on the server I had to change some environment variables of strapi :`DATABASE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: 600000`, `DATABASE_POOL_MAX: 100` and `DATABASE_POOL_MIN: 0` , after doing that configuration apparently the problem has not appeared again.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for sharing.